# GoLang Print the Number of Occurances of the Values in an Array

Tags: arrays, go

The following is my code  where I need to Print the number of occurances of each values in an array.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    //Initialize an array 
    inputArray := []int{10,20,30,56,67,90,10,20}
    printUniqueValue(inputArray)
}

func printUniqueValue( arr []int){
    //Create a   dictionary of values for each element
    var  dict map[int]int 
    count := 0
    for _ , num :=  range arr {
        dict[num] = count+1
    }
    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```

But I couldn't  construct the dictionary as I wish like ,  dict[10] should have value 2. 
Sample Expected Output :

```
dict[10] = 2
dict[20] = 2
dict[30] = 1
```

Error I  got:  panic: assignment to entry in nil map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize `dict` with a non-nil map; one way would be with `var dict = make(map[int]int)`.

Once you fix that, you will also need to deal with the logic error in `dict[num] = count+1`, where the count of that value is set to 1 (count is always 0) instead of one more than the previous value.

Comment: Just to point out: `dict` may not have same order as elements in `arr`!

Comment: More precisely, the elements of `dict` don't have an order. Each time you iterate over it, you may get them in a different order.

Answer (score 16):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    //Initialize an array 
    inputArray := []int{10,20,30,56,67,90,10,20}
    printUniqueValue(inputArray)
}

func printUniqueValue( arr []int){
    //Create a   dictionary of values for each element
    dict:= make(map[int]int)
    for _ , num :=  range arr {
        dict[num] = dict[num]+1
    }
    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```

This prints `map[67:1 90:1 10:2 20:2 30:1 56:1]`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here.

1. You are declaring `dict` as a map value, but it is not assigned any value and so is nil
2. You are not updating the count as you are expecting

To fix the issue with the map, use the make function to assign an empty map to the `dict` variable. As explained above.

You are expecting:

```
map[10:2 20:2 30:1 56:1 67:1 90:1]
```

But even if the map was initialised correctly, you would get:

```
map[10:1 20:1 30:1 56:1 67:1 90:1]
```

Don't use a counter outside of the map itself. Use the existing value.

According to [the Go tour](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/22) maps return a zero value when queried with a non-existing key. This is a nice feature for this task, see the below code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    inputArray := []int{10,20,30,56,67,90,10,20}
    printUniqueValue(inputArray)
}

func printUniqueValue(arr []int) {
    dict := make(map[int]int)
    for _ , num :=  range arr {
        // dict[num] will return 0 if it hasn't yet been initialised
        dict[num] = dict[num] + 1
    }
    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make use of make function or map literals to create a non nil map. ref: https://go.dev/blog/maps

example of using map literals.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    inputArray := []int{10,20,30,56,67,90,10,20}
    printUniqueValue(inputArray)
}

func printUniqueValue( arr []int){
    dict := map[int]int{}
    for _, num := range arr {
        dict[num]++
    }
    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```